# Pintech PT-710 sensor identification problem

Tags: sensor, identification, hall-effect

[image]

Welcome all. I need some help with identifying a component. Recently I opened my Pintech PT-710 current probe and tried to see what type of sensor is used. Inside the jaw there is a single sensor shown in picture attached. I suspect it is Hall effect or TMR sensor. It has 4 pins in idle state following voltages are present.

PIN1 6.8V

PIN2 5.7V

PIN3 4.6V

PIN4 5.7V

All voltages are measured in respect to 9V battery “-“ terminal. This would suggest that pin 3 is sensor GND and pin 1 being sensor Vcc. Pin 2 and 4 being outputs seating at half of sensor supply. Last clue is a code on sensor itself “A115”. I understand no one has crystal ball to guess it. However, perhaps someone could give me some clues e.g. package type.